# How do I get a token (bearer) to run queries and where do I store it?

Tags: laravel, bearer-token, laravel-jetstream

How do I get a token (bearer) to run queries and where do I store it?

If I use `createToken('token')->plainTextToken`, I need to store it somewhere.

It is needed to send requests to the API connected as a separate package in the application with its routes.

The only workable solution was this:

```
Http::macro('test', function () {
    return Http::withHeaders([
        'Accept' => 'application/vnd.api+json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.api+json',
    ])->withToken(Auth::user()->createToken('token')->plainTextToken);
});
```

But I understand that generating a token for every request is weird at the very least, so I'm looking for the right solution.

As I understand it needs to be generated at login and somehow saved.

I use Laravel JetStream (InertiaJS).

P.S: Example request from the controller

```
$laboratory = Http::test()->get(config('app.url') . $this->api_path . '/laboratories/' . $id);

return Inertia::render('Laboratories/Show', ['laboratory' => $laboratory['data']]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Laravel Jetstream with Inertia.js/Breeze it will automatically do any authorization for you.

Mainly when storing bearer token, you store it in cookies, and depending on your javascript framework for example in VueJS you need to use Vuex to store it in a state to access it across components and put it in the Authorization header on every request to run a query if the route has an auth middleware.

Comment: I added a question, if I don't specify withToken I get a 401 Unauthorized error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to access the route in the vue file using Axios?

Comment: No, I make queries from the controller. I added an example to the question

Comment: When using the Laravel controller, you should use the model to do queries. You don’t have to connect to a different route using the controller. That’s why you’re having authentication issues.

For example, you could just do `Model::example()->get();`, and then just return it via Inertia::render() and in your vue.js file, you can just set your props to the data that you returned.

Comment: But I originally wanted to implement the API First application. First I created an API package, then I connected it via composer and make calls to it. Is this wrong?